# Convert color to specified color type

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors

I have color code like `0xff3a9bda, 0xff73bbf3`. I really don't know about this color type as I know that **these are NOT RGB, aRGB, HSB, or HEX**.

As I am working on web application, my problem is, I can get color code with JavaScript in RGB and HTML color code for any color and I **want to convert this color to above specified color type code**.

Could anybody please give me an idea or soluton for this?

Comment: No, nobody in the world will be able to help unless you can provide some explanation of the semantics of this "specified" color type. You've shown nothing but what appears to be 32-bit hex values.  They could mean anything.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space -- "ARGB values are typically expressed using 8 hexadecimal digits, with each pair of the hexadecimal digits representing the sample values of the Alpha, Red, Green and Blue channel, respectively."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure this isn't RGBA ?

`0xff3a9bda` would be `rgba(255,58,155,0.85)` (RGBA) or `rgba(58,155,218,1)` (ARGB)

You can do the conversion like this:

```
var c = 0xff3a9bda;
var r = (c & (0xff << 24)) >>> 24;
var g = (c & (0xff << 16)) >>> 16;
var b = (c & (0xff << 8)) >>> 8;
var a = (c & 0xff) / 0xff;
var rgba = 'rgba(' + [r,g,b,a].join(',') + ')';
```

Or like this:

```
var c = 0xff3a9bda;
var a = ((c & (0xff << 24)) >>> 24) / 0xff;
var r = (c & (0xff << 16)) >>> 16;
var g = (c & (0xff << 8)) >>> 8;
var b = c & 0xff;
var rgba = 'rgba(' + [r,g,b,a].join(',') + ')';
```

**Try here:** http://jsfiddle.net/gX6ds/1/

---

Convert `#RRGGBB` to this format:

```
var rgb = 'AABBCC';
var c = 0xff000000 + parseInt(rgb, 16);
alert('0x' + c.toString(16));
```

Convert R, G, B values to this format:

```
var R = 0xAA, G = 0xBB, B = 0xCC;
var c = 0xff000000 + (R << 16) + (G << 8) + B;
alert('0x' + c.toString(16));
```

Comment: thought the same thing, but rgba is `255,58,155,[0-1]`

Comment: It's basically a hexadecimal colour which includes the alpha channel (ARGB). IE's CSS filters use this colour format (for example, the gradient filter).

Comment: @Eonasdan - No it isn't.  RGBA is a 32-bit color space, and the A component is still represented as an integer from 0 to 255.

Comment: so this site: http://css-tricks.com/2151-rgba-browser-support/ and this site: http://www.css3.info/introduction-opacity-rgba/ and this site: http://24ways.org/2009/working-with-rgba-colour are wrong?

Comment: okay so, if it is RGBA..then I need to convert color from RGB OR html color code to ARGB by Javascript.. any solution?

Comment: @Eonasdan - Not wrong, but you're misinterpreting.  The parameters expected by the `rgba()` utility have nothing to do with how the actual colorspace works.  More to the point, what do you expect values in your `[0-1]` range to actually look like, in hex/binary?

Comment: @Eonasdan: wikipedia is then wrong: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA ( anecdotal evidence ftw)

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to overcomplicate the matter.  You've got a 32-bit color value there, which almost certainly means you have 4 color components (R, G, B, A) at 8 bits per component.  If the format is not ARGB then it is probably RGBA, but that will be up to you to figure out.  It is certainly simple enough to do so via trial and error.

In any case once you know which bits represent which color components, all you need to do is extract out R, G, and B (see arnaud576875's answer) and then concatenate them together like `#<R><G><B>` to get your HTML color code.

Then you take your A component and set it as the `opacity` of whatever element you want to apply this color to.  As in:

```
#coloredElem {
    color: #<R><G><B>;
    opacity: <A / 255.0>;
}
```